# ssh to multiple servers and run the application specific commands rather than OS commands

Tags: ssh

My script from source server trying ssh onto multiple servers and run the application specific command which i can say, other than Operating system commands (like cat, chmod..), i get the error like command: not found. Below is the script.

```
for host in $(cat hosts_list.txt)
do
ssh $host chk_auto_up > "cmd_output.txt"
done
```

Can anyone assist, what i have to include in the script to identify the command and run and write the output ot the file ?

I have error saying that command not found

Comment: Is the OS command an alias or in a non-standard path?

Answer (score 1):

you just edit the line:

```
ssh $host /path/of/chk_auto_up > "cmd_output.txt"
```

Define the absolute path of the command.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that how to run external command over ssh remotely.

```
for host in $(cat /***/thishost/**/username/hosts_list.txt)
do
ssh "$host"
. /**/***/*****/*****/******.${HOST}  
chk_auto_up >> "/****/thishost/***/*****/cmd_output.txt"
exit
done
```

Details:

1. `hosts_list.txt`  --> I have list of servers to login by ssh
2. `ssh "$host"`  --> ssh login happens on the first server.
3. `. /**/***/*****/*****/******.${HOST}` --> external command binary path is available here
4. `chk_auto_up >> "/****/thishost/***/*****/cmd_output.txt"`   --> Run the command and writes the output to source server.

Comment: Please read [how to format posts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).